# When using plupload HOWTO duplicate file object when selected & submit it separately for a related server-side processing

Tags: javascript, file-upload, thumbnails, filepath, plupload

I am using [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) to let users upload images. But I also want to generate thumbnails for preview before they finally decide to keep it. I understand currently "Image preview" feature is not present in plupload. So to work around this I decided to submit a new form containing just one file for each image added, & let the server process it & return a thumbnail.

Now my question is how do I get the handle on the file object from the plupload so that I can create an "input" file field dynamically.

Currently I iterate over uploader.files & set input.name but I dont know how to set the input.value field, since I cant seem to get the complete file path of the file added.

I am up for any suggestions (in addition to replacing this approach completely), I just need thumbnail of the file selected for upload.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe my answer is a bit late, but I searched today for a similar solution and came up with the following approach. **It will only work with the HTML5 Runtime**.

As there is no way to get the file objects from plupload, I changed the onchange event of the dynamically created input field and store the file objects for myself. This is done by binding to the PostInit-Event.

After that I can show the image to the user by using the FileReader API introduced with HTML 5. So there is no need to send the image to the server. See my FilesAdded Listener below.

```
    // Currently added File Objects                
    var nativeFiles = {};

    var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes : 'html5,html4',
        // Your settings...
    });

    uploader.bind('PostInit', function(up, params) {
        // Initialize Preview.
        if(uploader.runtime == "html5") {
            var inputFile = document.getElementById(uploader.id + '_html5');
            var oldFunction = inputFile.onchange;

            inputFile.onchange = function() {
                nativeFiles = this.files;
                oldFunction.call(inputFile);
            }
        }
    });


    uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {       
        for (var i in files) {
            // Your code...

            // Load Preview
            if(uploader.runtime == "html5") {
                var fileObject = uploader.getFile(files[i].id);
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = (function(file, id) {
                    return function(e) {
                        var span = document.getElementById('thumb_'+id);
                        span.innerHTML = "<img src='"+e.target.result+"'/>";
                      };
                })(nativeFiles[i], files[i].id);

                reader.readAsDataURL(nativeFiles[i]);
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks @dominik for replying. I actually went ahead and submitted the file as soon it was selected and then relied on server-side code to send back a thumbnail & then saved it permanently to the backend once the user is satisfied with it. I know this might cause unnecessary bandwidth usage but this was the only all-platform-compliant solution I could think of.

Comment: why do you need to bind to the change event if you can get the file object in the `FilesAdded` via `uploader.getFile(files[i].id)`?